# Can't use N() with arrays with Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I want to compute the weighted mean (WM) of column A (the one on the left) using the weights in column B (right). The problem is that column A can have character values.

```
    A       B
1   9.1     625
2   8.3     74
3   9.1     655
4   --      20
5   8.8     48
6   10.0    691
7   8.2     107
8   6.4     34
9   7.1     25
10  8.4     126
```

I tried to compute the WM with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10;B1:B10)/SUM(B1:B10)
```

but it consider the "--" as zero, leaving the weight unchanged. Instead it should be ignoring both the value and the weight for that row.

So I thought of using array formulas. The first one (F1) coerce to numbers the values so that "--" becomes 0. The second one (F2) force to 0 the weights if the corresponding value is not a number:

```
F1. {=SUM(N(A1:A10)*B1:B10)} # = 21885.5

F2. {=SUM(IF(N(A1:A10)=0;0;1)*B1:B10)} # = 2405

F3. =F1/F2 # = 9.1, the weighted average
```

- F1 is wrong; it should be 21925.5, but instead looks like just A1 (9.1) is considered in the calculation, not the whole array. If I set A1 to "--" than F1 becomes 0. So it seems that ranges don't play well with N() and instead of an array, just the first transformed value is returned.
- F2 is wrong too;  it should be 2385, that is B4 (20) should not be considered in the sum. The problem is the same. In facts if I change the formula to `=SUM(IF(A1:A10;1;0)*B1:B10)` and change A4 to blank the result is correct.

To solve the problem so I need to change "--" to blanks and use this formula for the WM:

```
{=SUM(A1:A10*IF(A1:A10;1;0)*B1:B10)/SUM(IF(A1:A10;1;0)*B1:B10)}
```

My question is: is there a way to use N() with arrays or just a limited number of functions work with arrays and there's nothing I can do?

Thanks

Comment: you could try this array formula: `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A10);A1:A10*B1:B10))/SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A10);B1:B10))`  It skips any non numeric values in A.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think you meant `sumproduct` for your first `sum` function

Comment: No, it works this way.  But I like your response.  Replacing the Sum with Sumproduct as I have it would not work.  It works the way you have it and it is better than mine. @ForwardEd Just goes to show that there are many ways to do the same thing in Excel.

Comment: @doh I missed the first part of the sentence where you declared it as a CSE Array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner Apparently we all miss read the question.  We were not supposed to come up with the weighted mean.  He wanted to know about N() and its use with arrays.

Comment: @ForwardEd hence the reason mine was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fight with your data.

In **C1** enter:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,0)
```

and copy down.  Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),B1,0)
```

and copy down.  This effectively removes junk from the weighting process.  In another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C1:C10*D1:D10)/SUM(D1:D10)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you want to get *N()* to yield an array, you must add zero:

In this example in **C1** I enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((N(A1:A3))*(B1:B3))
```

and in **C2** I enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((N(A1:A3+0))*(B1:B3))
```

[image]

as you see, only **C2** is correct.

Comment: I originally had a different number than you Gary and I thought it was because you used a * between the two ranges instead of a , or ; depending on your system settings...then I realized it does not make a difference.  Its actually better since , and ; are system dependent.  Which is what caused my initial error.  When I switched to a , and * I got the same number so +1 for use of the * instead.

Comment: Actually the point was not to have to use new cells for the intermediate calculation, but to use array operations like It's usual in languages like R or Python. The question is about whether is it true that only a subset of excel functions do use arrays. If it is true, than you simply cannot use some functions like N() and there's no way out of it (MS could at least put it in the docs).

Comment: @Bakaburg  See my **EDIT#1:** ..............there are some functions that must be prodded a little.

Comment: @Bakaburg  I am sorry that I did not understand the real point of your question.

Comment: I tried the solution in the EDIT and it works, but just with empty cells, while it gives error if text is inside the cells. But better than nothing (it well know that excel in quite non linear in how it has been conceived). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10;B1:B10)/SUMPRODUCT(B1:B10*(isnumber(A1:A10))
```

This returned a value of 9.193082 for the WM.  The isnumber portion basically makes any value in column B equal to 0 when the corresponding value in A is not a number

Apparently I misread the question, your question was all about the usage of N() with arrays...I do not know, but what I can say is the formula above has no need of the N() function.